# How do I persist objects in the session scope on POST requests with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I am putting together a few simple pages with Spring and would like to add some data to an object that persists for the session. It seems to persist for GET requests but not for those made using the POST method.

I have a UserData component as follows:

```
package com.mycompany.controllers.components;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("session")
public class UserData {

    private boolean loggedIn;

    public UserData() {
        loggedIn = false;
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return loggedIn;
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    }
}
```

I have a controller as follows:

```
package com.mycompany.controllers;
...
@RestController
@Scope("session")
public class DefaultController {

    @Autowired
    UserData userData;

    ...

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity index() {

        printUserData(userData);

        ResponseEntity entity;
        if((entity = authenticate(userData)) != null) {
            return entity;
        }
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/setloggedIn")
    public ResponseEntity setLoggedIn() {

        printUserData(userData);

        userData.setLoggedIn(true);
    }

    @PostMapping("/logIn" )
    public ResponseEntity logIn(@RequestBody LogInDTO dto) {

        printUserData(userData);
        ...
        userData.setLoggedIn(true);
    }


    protected static void printUserData(UserData user) {
        if(user== null) {
            LOG.info("UserData is null");
            return;
        }

        LOG.info("UserData logged in: {}", user.isLoggedIn());
    }
}
```

- When I navigate to "/" the output of `UserData.isLoggedIn()` is false as expected.
- When I make a post request to "/logIn" the output, again as expected, is false. Following some parameter validation the method `UserData.setLoggedIn(true)` is called but navigating to "/" the output is still false.
- When I navigate to "/setLoggedIn" then loggedIn is false initially but this also sets loggedIn to true, now all requests to "/" or "/setLoggedIn" result in an output of true.
- Further POST requests to "/logIn" give the output of false

Am I missing something or is this normal behavior?

**UPDATE 1**

When I check the session ID on the GET requests I can see that it is equal to the JSESSIONID stored in my cookies. I see a different session ID for every POST request.

So the question is, how do I send the JSESSIONID along with the POST request. I'm currently performing the request as follows:

```
fetch('/logIn', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username: txtUsername.value,
        password: txtPassword.value
    }),
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
})
.then(result => {
    result.text().then(function(text) {
        if(result.status == 200) {
            location.reload();
        } else {
            alert("Error:\n" + text);
        }
    });
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
    alert("Error:\n" + e);

});
```

**UPDATE  2**

I found that the JSESSIONID cookie is HttpOnly and cannot be read by JavaScript and could that be the reason it's not sent with the POST request? Causing the servlet to create a new session every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetch command needs ""credentials: 'include'" set to true. This allows the http-only cookies to be sent with the post requests, thus the server is able to resolve the current session. Working fetch code looks like this:

```
fetch('/logIn', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: txtUsername.value,
    password: txtPassword.value
  }),
  credentials: 'include', // <<< FIX
  headers : {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(result => {
  result.text().then(function(text) {
    if(result.status == 200) {
        location.reload();
    } else {
        alert("Error:\n" + text);
    }
  });
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
  alert("Error:\n" + e);
});
```